# Numeric Placeholders like VSCode Snippets in IntelliJ Live Templates

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, webstorm, live-templates

In VSCode there are numeric tab-stops or placeholders like $1, $2, ...

So in VSCode JS Snippets,

```
import ${2:objectIWantToImport} from ${1:package}
```

first stops on *package* placeholder and then goes back to *objectIWantToImport* placeholder

But in IntelliJ WebStorm I have tried similar something to this,

```
import $2$ from "$1$";
```

which doesn't work. The tab-stops are serial from left to right.

How do I get a way around it to first stop on 1 and then on 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can click on Edit Variables button in the Live Template settings and swap the table lines there, that'll change the order the placeholders are visited.